# Star favorite users

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I realise SE is about questions and aswers which are judged on their own merits, regardless of the person who asks or answers. People's contributions to the community are represented by more or less objective metrics like reputation or tag scores.

However, once in a while I wish I could recognize users who were especially helpful, or just nice or cool, beyond the simple upvote. Maybe if I had the chance to help them, answering their questions would've been my priority. Or perhaps I'd consider editing their answer to correct eventual mistakes, when I wouldn't do the same to help average Joe. Or I just want to "bookmark" them for future referece, because I like how their personal statement is phrased.

The simplest way I can see to achieve all this is to add the same kind of star to user profiles as we have for questions. This wouldn't affect such users in any way (though it may be a good idea to display how many people starred them in their profile), and I would see a star on their card and have a list of them in my profile for quick access.

Comment: The simplest way to achieve this now is to award a bounty to them for a great answer that they have given.

Answer (score 10):

This has been asked before, and will be closed as a dupe soon.

Just to touch on something in your question which is slightly different from the dupe(s).

> Or perhaps I'd consider editing their
>   answer to correct eventual mistakes, when I wouldn't do the same to
>   help average Joe

While this is kind to *your* friends/favourites, it's not kind to the site and its users as a whole.

We'd end up with groups of people helping each other, answering friends only, and this risks limiting how much help people get from each other.

Consider other users will also do the same as you, and only help their friends. Then *you* become the "average Joe" and don't get as much help as you would have done without such groups.

---

You can go into chat room(s) if you want to find like-minded people, who you then may help out a bit more than you would others. :)